# Logical operation in OCaml error

Tags: ocaml

I'm trying to write a function in OCaml that solves a logical operation. This attempt was successful:

```
let rec tf =function
  |B b->b
  |V s->failwith "not good"
  |And(e1,e2)->tf e1&&tf e2
  |Or(e1,e2)->tf e1||tf e2
  |Neg b-> not (tf b);;
```

But when I write the following function, the programs warns me about some error:

```
type bv = B of bool | V of string | Neg of bv
             | And of bv * bv | Or of bv * bv;;
module MS=Map.Make(String);;

let  prop x map=
  let rec aux=function
  |B b->b
  |Neg b-> not (aux b)
  |V s->try aux(B (MS.find s map)) with Not_found->failwith ""
  |And(e1,e2)->aux e1&&aux e2
  |Or(e1,e2)->aux e1||aux e2
  in aux x;;          

    Characters 145-148:
    |And(e1,e2)->aux e1&&aux e2
     ^^^
Error: This variant pattern is expected to have type exn
       The constructor And does not belong to type exn
```

Where map is a (string*bool) map. If the argument "x" of the function is a string, then it will look for it in the map and get the boolean value, then use it in further calculus. if x cannot be found, it throws an exception and ends the function.
I know it has something to do with the V s matching but I have no idea what is wrong here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me show, how an indenter that is aware of OCaml syntax will indent your code:

```
let prop x map=
  let rec aux=function
    |B b->b
    |Neg b-> not (aux b)
    |V s->try aux(B (MS.find s map)) with Not_found->failwith ""
                                        | And(e1,e2)->aux e1&&aux e2
                                        | Or(e1,e2)->aux e1||aux e2
  in aux x;;
```

Now, it is pretty obvious, why `And` and `Or` are expected to be exceptions.

You can parenthesize your call to aux, e.g.,

```
let prop x map =
  let rec aux=function
    |B b->b
    |Neg b-> not (aux b)
    |V s-> (try aux(B (MS.find s map)) with Not_found->failwith "")
    |And(e1,e2)->aux e1&&aux e2
    |Or(e1,e2)->aux e1||aux e2
  in aux x;;
```

However, this is not a good idea, to install exception handlers around each recursive call, as this lead to the installation of `N` exception records on the stack thus defeating the idea of tail recursion. It is better to rewrite your algorithm as follows:

```
 let prop x map=
  let rec aux=function
    |B b->b
    |Neg b-> not (aux b)
    |V s when MS.mem s map -> aux (B (MS.find s map))
    |V s -> invalid_arg ("Unbound variable: " ^ s)
    |And(e1,e2) -> aux e1&&aux e2
    |Or(e1,e2) -> aux e1||aux e2 in
  aux x
```